# Magento 2 Fatal error after saved Category Custom Image Attribute

Tags: magento2

I've added a custom image attribute to my category with Magento 2 Module Generator from https://mage2gen.com/ (Magento version 2.2)
Everything is perfect, but when I upload an image to the attribute and save category, an error occurred:

> Fatal error: Method Magento\Ui\TemplateEngine\Xhtml\Result::__toString() must not throw an exception, caught Error: Cannot use string offset as an array in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\vendor\magento\module-ui\Component\Wrapper\UiComponent.php on line 0

This is my **InstallData.php**

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    private $eavSetupFactory;
    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    public function install(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup,
        ModuleContextInterface $context
    ) {
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY,
            'thumbnail_image',
            [
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'label' => 'Thumbnail Image',
                'input' => 'image',
                'sort_order' => 5,
                'source' => '',
                'global' => 0,
                'visible' => true,
                'required' => false,
                'user_defined' => false,
                'default' => '',
                'group' => 'General Information',
                'backend' => 'Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Attribute\Backend\Image'
            ]
        );

     }
}
```

And the **category_form.xml**

```
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
<fieldset name="general">
    <field name="thumbnail_image">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="required" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                </item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">5</item>
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">fileUploader</item>
                <item name="label" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Thumbnail Image</item>
                <item name="uploaderConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="url" path="catalog/category_image/upload" xsi:type="url"/>
                </item>
                <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/uploader/uploader</item>
                <item name="previewTmpl" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog/image-preview</item>
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">category</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>
</fieldset>
```

I am sure the value is saved OK (checked in database for `eav_attribute`, `catalog_category_entity_varchar` tables) and the image is uploaded into `\pub\media\catalog\category`

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this fix
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5438/#issuecomment-337203020

it's helped me.